# Como alterar a visibilidade de um input ao selecionar um item no select e nao alterar todos no ngFor

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-8

Quando seleciona o item 'title' é para ocultar o input. Mas quando seleciono outro item de outro index do ngFor, o input selecionado 'title' volta a ser exibido.
[Exemplo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/component-angular-select-change?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema é que você esta fazendo isso com uma variável do tipo inteiro:

```
idvalue = 0;
```

Para solucionar o seu problema, crie um array para receber o valor de cada linha:

```
idvalue = [];
```

E altere o seu método:

```
changeValue(event, index) {
    console.log(event, index);
    this.evento = event === index + '_title';
    this.idvalue = index;
}
```

Para:

```
changeValue(event, index) {
    this.idvalue[index] = event.includes('title') ? index : -1;
}
```

Desta forma verificamos se a opção selecionada é o "title" e atribuímos o valor na posição do array correspondente a linha que você deseja ocultar o campo.

E por fim não é mais necessária a opção "evento" no seu input:

```
<input [hidden]="i === idvalue[i]" id="id_{{i}}" name="name_{{1}}" type="text" value="">
```

[Resultado](https://stackblitz.com/edit/component-angular-select-change-b14uo4?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Entendi! Agradeço pelos detalhes na explicação. Funcionou perfeitamente!